# If a key is used to encrypt that same key, is the computational cost to brute force it decreased?

Tags: symmetric, brute-force-attack, attack

If a key $d$ is used to encrypt a message $m$ that is identical to the key $d$, resulting in a cipher $c$

$c = \text{Encrypt}(m, d) = \text{Encrypt}(d, d)$

is the computational cost to brute force $d$ lower than if the key $d \ne m$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the encryption scheme.

In the IND-CPA (or even IND-CCA) security game, the adversary is not given the secret key $d$ (obviously) and hence cannot ask for $\mathrm{Enc}(d,d)$.

In other words: an encryption scheme where $\mathrm{Enc}(d,d) = d$ for all keys $d$ can still be IND-CPA(/CCA) secure (but they'd be completely useless for your scenario).

Comment: This is related to the concept of Circular Security...